# Function with static int

Tags: c, static

I have this C code:

```
void increase(int x)
{
    static int i=0;
    x = i + x;
    i++;
    printf("x=%d, i=%d\n", x, i);
}
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        increase(i);
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
x=0, i=1
x=2, i=2
x=4, i=3
x=6, i=4
i=4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I do not understand how to get those results. When I try to run through the code myself, I am confused by the `static int`, as well as the function; since the function is called with `i` as the argument.

Is `int i` treated as `int x` during the function because the function is initialized as `increasing(int x)`?

Also, since the 3rd expression in the for loop is `i++`, and there is an `i++` in the function, shouldn't each i value increase by increments of 2? Thank you!!

Comment: Hm... a bit too many questions at once... call by value vs. call by reference, scope, `static`... perhaps better ask one question at a time?

Comment: Both i's are different, which are local to its function block. There are two i's

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Since i is declared static its value increments on every function call (increase(i)).
The two i++ statements are in totally different scopes and have nothing to do with each other. You might as well treat them as two separate variables.
In the main function initially i=0. This value of i is passed to x in increase(x). x is now 0 and i is 0 because of static int i=0. x=x+i makes x=0. Then i++ makes i=1. This is demonstrated in first line of output. Again in main loop i is now 1.This is passed to x in increase(x). x is now 1. The i in increase() is also 1 but only because it is mentioned as static , not because the i in main is 1. x = x+i gives x=2. i++ makes i=2. And so on

```
void increase(int x)
{
    static int i=0;
    x = i + x;
    i++;
    printf("x=%d, i=%d\n", x, i);
}
```

Here i increases by 1 as shown in output.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        increase(i);
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Here x is passed an increasing value -> 0,1,2,3
which is then increased by i-> 0,1,2,3 everytime giving:
0,2,4,6.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of which `i` is visible in which function.

```
void increase(int x)
{static int i=0; /* the only i seen inside this question */
    x = i + x; /* using this functions i, reading it */
    i++;       /* using this functions i, read-writing it */
    printf("x=%d, i=%d\n", x, i); /* reading */
}
```

The `i` in above function only ever is subjected to `i++` (apart from the initialisation to 0) and otherwise does not change. Being `static` it does however carry the value from one execution of the function over to the next, i.e. the initialisation `=0` only happens during the first execution.
The `x` in above function carries the value of the `i` in below function.

The `i` in below function is counting through the loop, but is not affected anywhere else.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i; /* the only i seen inside this question */
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) /* using this functions i, including to increment it */
        increase(i); /* handing it as parameter to function,
                        the value given is seen within the function as x */
    printf("i=%d\n", i); /* reading it for output */
    return 0;
}
```